# What type of regression analyses can I use on non-normally distributed data?

Tags: r, regression

I have a set of data that are non-normally distributed. I am trying to find which independent variable predicts the dependent variable. This is why I want to use regression. But since I am not familiar with statistical tests involving non-normally distributed data, I am asking for some help regarding this matter. Please tell me the name of the test that is most appropriate for use in this case.

Update: The dependent variable is always positive. It consists of scores calculated on questionnaires.
I checked the errors using the Shapiro test, and they are not normally distributed.

Update 2: Scores are summed, and they range from 0 to 100. So, technically, they have an upper bound. Same for all the independent variables. All are scores that have an upper bound and are all positive.

Comment: A normal distribution of the response variable is not a standard assumption of OLS. The common normality assumption that let’s us do parameter inference is a normality distributed error term. These are very different assumptions. Run your regression and then check the residuals. If they look about normal, then you probably have an error that is about normal. (Related, you definitely don’t need normal distributions for your predictor variables!)

Comment: If linear regression isn't a good idea for your data on other grounds, which is entirely possible, we can't advise on good practice, including a good model (which is the main question, not which test to use), without knowing more about the data. Perhaps you can post the dataset if it is not small or at least show us some graphs to get a better idea. For example, you don't say anything about the dependent variable. Is it counted? measured? Always positive? Ever zero? Ever negative? etc.

Comment: Scores calculated on questionnaires is helpful, but not enough to advise. Do you mean scores 1 to 5 or some sum with an upper bound?

Comment: @NickCox Can you please look at update 2 and advise me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Could be a logit on proportions, but still to advise well.

Comment: ... still hard ...

Answer (score 1):

For ordinary least squares regression, distributional assumptions apply to the residuals, not to the variables themselves. The predictor variables are entirely excluded from distributional assumptions.

Comment: Distributional assumptions are weak, and do not require normality of residuals even for OLS

Comment: @Ed The usual (iid Gaussian) dIstributional assumptions apply to the errors, not the residuals, and are only really needed when using something that assumes those errors are Gaussian (such as the usual tests and intervals) -- unless you want reasonably efficient estimates of the coeffcients, in which case you do need something not too far from those assumptions (with the usual estimator)